# DT Shiny different custom column header by column

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt, htmltools

my css skills are extremely limited but assuming the following example:

```
  sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
     class = 'display',
     thead(
        tr(
           th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
           th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
           th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
        ),
        tr(
           lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
        )
     )
  ))
  datatable(head(iris, 10), 
     container = sketch, options = list(
     initComplete = JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
        "}")
  ))
```

How would I change the color coding of the first two column headers into say blue so that both rows of the column header `Sepal,Length` and `Sepal,Width` are blue, but retaining as another color the following structure `Petal,Length` and `Petal,Width`

After Stephane's initial answer, I added an example.

[image: example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the option `headerCallback`.

```
datatable(head(iris, 10), 
          container = sketch, options = list(
            headerCallback = JS(
              "function( thead, data, start, end, display ) {
      $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(3).css('color', 'red');
      $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(4).css('color', 'red');
      $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(5).css('color', 'blue');
      $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(6).css('color', 'blue');
              }"
            ),
            initComplete = JS(
              "function(settings, json) {",
              "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
              "}")
          ))
```

The `.closest('thead')` is needed when the header has multiple rows.

Is it what you want? I'm not sure I have correctly understood your request.

[image]

---

To change the background color:

```
library(DT)

sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))

headerCallback <- "function( thead, data, start, end, display ) {
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(0).css('background-color', 'green');
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(1).css('background-color', 'red');
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(2).css('background-color', 'blue');
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(3).css('background-color', 'red');
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(4).css('background-color', 'red');
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(5).css('background-color', 'blue');
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(6).css('background-color', 'blue');
}"

datatable(head(iris, 10), 
          container = sketch, options = list(
            headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
          )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Stephane thank you! I'm sure your initial answer will not go to waste in the future - please see example added - the plan is to make it easy for users to discriminate column structures not by the font color but by the background color. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @J.Doe. You're welcome. I've just edited my answer to show how to change the background color.